# Can we have a jar repository in VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm new to VSTS. We are about to start using VSTS as our repository for code and build process. Can I have a repository in VSTS where I can load all jars (like maven) and then use the same to build my java application? Basically, I'm trying to get Maven feature with VSTS

Answer (score 0):

You can put jar files in the VSTS repository but needs to clone them to the build agent.

To clone extra repository, you can add **Command Line step/task** to call git clone command.

On the other hand, there is **Maven step/task** already. [Build your Java app with Maven](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/get-started/java-maven)